# How to repeat watermark background

Tags: microsoft-word, watermark

How can you repeat a watermark image as a background in a MS Word 2010 document? I want the patterned image to repeat to cover the entire document from top to bottom and side to side.

Comment: a custom picture watermark or a standard watermark?

Comment: Can you use the header and footer?

Answer (score 1):

Use Page Layout> Page Color> Fill Effects> Picture.  You'll need to edit the picture to be transparent prior to doing this though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Page Layout tab, Watermark button. There are plenty of options, including a "Custom Watermark."

[image]